# Why is the posterior proportional to $P(X=x|C=c_i)P(C=c_i)$?

Tags: bayesian, naive-bayes

When we are trying to maximum a posterior, we apply Bayesian rule to convert them into posterior probabilities!

$P(C=c_i|X=x) = P(X=x|C=c_i)P(C=c_i) / P(X=x)$ 
proportional to $P(X=x|C=c_i)P(C=c_i)$,
but how can i be sure that it is really the case?

Comment: Are you asking 'how can I be sure Bayes rule is true?' or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The denominator can be written as:

$P(X=x)=\sum_{C}P(X=x|C=c_i)P(C=c_i)$

and the sum is over all possible values of $C$. $P(X=x)$, as you can see, does not depend on $C$. With fixed $X$ (*i.e.* with your fixed data) hence can be considered as a constant.

Thus $P(C=c_i|X=x) \propto P(X=x|C=c_i)P(C=c_i)$.

The right side of the above equation will be called the *"unnormalized posterior density".*